# is the package 'changes' only used for texts without any latex commands?

Tags: changes, trackchanges

I want to use `changes` package to track the changes. However, I realized that if the text includes some latex commands such as `\paragraph`, `\begin{itemize}`, `begin{equation}` etc., then any of changes commands (`\added`, `\deleted`, `\replaced`) do not work. Is there a way to adapt the commands of changes such that they will ignore the latex commands.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}

\added{
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

The error is `Undefined control sequence. }`

Comment: `\added{\textit{Some more blindtext}}` works for me... Please show a compilable document that has your issue

Comment: You are right it works for me too, but it seems it works for font styles and font sizes but not for other types of commands. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: There is still no compilable code however. Most likely you get into trouble because of fragile commands. `\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{\begin{itemize}\item foo\end{itemize}}` will work with `\added{\foo}` as well, but as soon as you try `\listofchanges`, there will be new trouble

Comment: The compilable code is added.

Comment: Yes, that's better, but I think the `changes` package is not meant to add such more 'sophisticated' structures like `itemize` etc.

Comment: You should take a look at VCS (version control system). I'd recommend git and use the possibilities of gitdiff.